# The noun of "furious"

Tags: word-form

> I was in a furious state.
>
> I was in a state of **furiousity**.
>
> I can understand you're being furious about that.
>
> I can understand your **furiousity** about that.

The usage of *furiousity* here is most probably wrong. What would be the correct form of furious here?

Comment: The word you're looking for is *furiosity*.

Comment: @Sander Both furiousity and furiosity aren't in my dictionary, but you may very well be right.

Comment: change the dictionary! :)

Comment: You can find it here: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/furiosity

Comment: tbh, I'd only use furiosity if I were joking - like the opposite of warmth is coolth ;) [sorry, my autocorrect hates those words…] Fury would be the common term.

Comment: "His attacks came with such furiosity that none could stand before him."    This is a way that I would use that term.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan The problem is that *furiosity* is extremely rare; there's not a single instance in COCA. I won't say I've never heard it; but I'm pretty sure that if heard that sentence my hearing apparatus would reject *furiosity* and substitute *ferocity*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The normal noun of furious is fury. "Furiosity" is extremely seldom. It is not registered in Oxford's COD, book form. If Merriam-Webster has it, they should mention: rare or better extremely rare.
COCA, if I handle it right, has no instance for furiosity.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is unequivocally **[furiousness](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/furiousness)** or **[fury](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fury)**, essentially the noun forms of the adjective "furious".

Comment: I beg to differ, what about *furiosity*? That word is also a noun of the adjective *furious*.

Comment: It is in the Merriam-Webster dictionary. However, it is rather rare. I think *fury* might be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Furor.

In at least your example "I can understand your furiousity about that", I think "I can understand your furor about that" works better.

Comment: That's not [what furor means](https://www.bing.com/search?q=furor).